# Foe a piecewise r.v. $Y$, how does one calculate $P(Y\leq x)$?

Tags: probability

The problem is this:

A line segment of length $L$ is cut at any point $X$ on the line. $X$ is uniformly distributed over the whole line segment. After the cut, what is the probability that the ratio of the smaller piece to the larger piece is less than $1/4$?

This is what I tried:

Let $$Y(X)=
 \begin{cases} 
      \frac{L-X}{X} & \frac L2 \leq X\leq L \\
      \frac{X}{L-X} & 0\leq X < \frac L2
   \end{cases}
$$
Now, $$\mathbb{P}(Y(X)\leq \frac12)=\mathbb{P}(Y(X)\leq \frac12|X < \frac L2)\mathbb{P}(X<\frac L2)+\mathbb{P}(Y(X)\leq \frac12|X \geq \frac L2)\mathbb{P}(X\geq \frac L2)$$
However, this evaluates to $1/5$ and the book says it is twice this much. I do not know if this method is the correct one to use, but what I am trying to do above is conditioning so that I can choose unambiguously one part of the piecewise function and then solve for $X$ in the corresponding inequality and then use the pmf.

I have read answers on the internet and they do not use conditioning, instead they simply state that $X$ is either less than or equal to $L/5$ or that it is greater than $4L/5$. What I want to understand is how would I solve this question formally (i.e. for any piecewise r.v. $Y$ how does one calculate $\mathbb{P} (Y \leq x)$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right to partition.   You went awry by using conditioning, rather than joint probabilities.

You have $Y=
 \begin{cases} 
      \frac{X}{L-X} & 0\leq X < \frac L2\\
      \frac{L-X}{X} & \frac L2 \leq X\leq L \\ 0 &\text{else}
   \end{cases}$

Then by partitioning by cases:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y<1/2) &= \mathsf P(\tfrac X{L-X}<\tfrac 12, 0\leq X<\tfrac L 2)+\mathsf P(\tfrac {L-X}X<\tfrac 12, \tfrac L 2\leq X\leq L)
\\[1ex] & =\mathsf P(3X<L, 0\leq X\leq \tfrac L2)+\mathsf P(2L<3X, \tfrac L2\leq X\leq L) \\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(0\leq X\leq \tfrac 1 3L)+\mathsf P(\tfrac 2 3L\leq X\leq L) \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 23 \end{align}$$

Now, can you do $\mathsf P(Y\leq 1/4)$ ?

Comment: When one partitions by cases, what is one formally doing?

Comment: @Gaucho Partitioning the sample space into disjoint subsets, the probabilities of which are strictly additive ... and hopefully more easily calculated.

Comment: It is like saying $A=(A\cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$ but without using the $B$?

Comment: @GuachoPerez  No, the $B$ in this case is the event of $0\leq X<\tfrac 12L$, and its complement is the event of $\tfrac 12L\leq X\leq L$ ; which partition the sample space and, conveniently, make $Y$ simpler to evaluate in each case.